# Facebook login with PHP - /me/friends

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-friends

I have the following PHP code which I am planning to use for my website. I also need to get the Facebook IDs of the user's friends who have also signed in to my website using my Facebook app before.

I created an app and in the "Status & Review" page I can see email, public_profile and user_friends permissions. When I try to make a request with "/me" only, I can get the user ID and firstname, lastname. So it works fine. But when I try with "/me/friends" following code returns an empty array. Although it is not very important for me, I can't get user's email either.

Do you guys have any idea how I can get this information? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('MY_APP_ID', 'MY_APP_SECRET');
$facebook = new Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('MY_REDIRECT_URL_HERE');
$session = $facebook->getSessionFromRedirect();
$session = new Facebook\FacebookSession($_SESSION['facebook']);
$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/friends');
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

Answer (score 2):

The permissions in the "Status & Review" Tab just mean that you don´t need to get them approved by Facebook, but you still need to request them in the authorization process. That is what the "scope" parameter is for: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/

Btw, i am not sure if you know, but you can only get the users who authorized your App too with /me/friends. So either you did not authorize the user correctly with the user_friends permission, or you just don´t have any friends using the App.